# Angular 2+ Import a Non Module into TS

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I made a library and it needs to support multiple applications. However one of the sites is non-angular and will not support "modules", hence I am unable to use "export" on my function.

My External library:

```
var foo = (function() {

    function MyFunction(){
    }

    MyFunciton.prototype.bar(){
    }

    return MyFunction;

}());
```

My Question:
How do I import this into my component.ts without an export?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your script in your `angular.json` file in the `scripts` section.

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
       //...
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/foo.js.js"
        ]
      },
```

In your component service, declare your variable. You can then use it without typescript complaining.

```
//declare this on top of your component/service
declare let foo: any;

myMethod()
{
 var inst = new foo();
 inst.bar();//call bar
}
```