# _path2.default.basename is not a function using convertapi in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, convertapi

I am trying to integrate the convertapi in my Angular 11 application using the following documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/convertapi

I need to convert the pdf's into images,

When I try to upload a file, I get

```
_path2.default.basename is not a function
```

Here is how I have implemented this in my component

Import

```
import ConvertAPI from 'convertapi';
```

Initiate

```
const convertapi = new ConvertAPI('my actual api-secret ');
```

And convert

```
convertapi.convert('jpg', { File: file }) //'file' is actual file object, also tried pdf url
      .then(function(result: any) {
      console.log(result)
})
.catch(function(e: any) {
      console.log(e.toString()); // this prints out the error message
});
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This library is a non module, please refer to this question on how to use it with Angular:
[Angular 2+ Import a Non Module into TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758943/angular-2-import-a-non-module-into-ts)

This is the documentation: https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-js